# Making partition only accessible to specific applications?

Tags: windows, partitioning, malware, disk-protection

As an added protection from malware besides up-to-date and off-line backups, I was wondering if a Windows partition could be made accessible only to such and such application, possibly after typing a password.

For instance, TotalCommander has [plug-ins](https://www.ghisler.com/plugins.htm) to access EXT4 partitions, which are unlikely to be supported by Windows malware, but this would restrict access to TC only.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> if a Windows partition could be made accessible only to such and such application

In theory yes,  however malwares are designed to ignore such restrictions.
Maybe you could be successful at the beginning,  however if many people would use this strategy I suppose malwares too would adapt quickly.
Also creating such a positive list and always provide a password could be tricky,  there are many programs which requires access to data for various reasons (anti malware, indexing,  disc defragmentation...)